# Can I HOST ASP.NET Core app and ASP.NET Framework app on the same server

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, server, hosting

I have a server that is currently hosting ASP.NET Framework applications and I have an ASP.NET Core application that I want to host on the same server. Will downloading ASP.NET Core Module (for hosting) cause any issues with the existing .NET Framework apps? And after that will hosting the new .NET Core application cause issues with the existing .NET Framework apps?

I know that you can develop .NET Core and .NET Framework at the same time since Core is self-contained, but can you host them on the same server at the same time?

*Note*: If you can include documentation from somewhere that supports your answer that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.